# Tables with images

Tags: bug, markdown

When writing a post, it renders a table with images just fine:

[image]

But once posted it doesn't render the table:
|test|blah|
|-|-|
|[image: test]|test|

Comment: Your question is currently unclear. You're reporting a bug, but the Markdown you've included in the question appears to be working fine. There are a variety of issues around table support and the differences between what the preview shows and what it rendered in the backend. It's very likely this is a duplicate of one of those reports, with the most likely being the duplicate target which has already been suggested here. For now, I'm going to close this as a duplicate of that question. Feel free to edit to clarify your question if the duplicate isn't correct.

Comment: Sorry, tested the "fix" from the provided link and forgot return it back to original...and yes, this seems to be duplicate question.